# Octave : I receive a dimension error: cat: dimension mismatch when doing cell2mat

Tags: math, octave

I have a cell array (class cell) with dimension that I try to convert to doubles.
I get a dimension error when I use cell2mat. (row 1 and kol 1 are not numeric)

```
debug> `class(mycsvdata)`
ans = cell
```

```
CCC=cell2mat(mycsvdata(2:end,2:end))
error: cat: dimension mismatch
error: called from
cell2mat at line 80 column 11
leesCsvPuur at line 7 column 2
verwerkStooq at line 37 column 8
handleStooq at line 77 column 1
testinvoer03 at line 72 column 1
```

```
debug> `size(mycsvdata)`
ans =
   9   7
```

I  tried cell2mat :

```
debug> `cell2mat{1 2 3; 4 5 6}`
ans =
   1   2   3
   4   5   6
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: can you show some of the contents of your cell array? (and their types?)

Comment: each row is like: 2008-02-14,33.0801,330.6899

Comment: Please add updates and clarifications to the question itself using [edit]. Also, what are the *type* of the data? From what you've shown us so far, this error could only happen if the numeric values in your comment are actually strings.

Comment: I could not show more than one row since this comment box doesn't allow a proper formatting. Its a comma separated csv and there are a few hundred rows. I exported it form an Office Calc export in csv format and read it with csc2cell function described here:  https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/csv2cell.m

Comment: Please don’t post additions to your question as comments or as an answer. Instead, edit your question. There’s a link just below the tags at the bottom of the question tag. You can also click this link: [edit].

Comment: people won't be able to help you with out a minimal working example. What's the smallest subset of your datafile that still produces the same error? Would a 5x5 subset do it? could you post that as blocktext or a code block like you did above?  for editing options you can see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @patpin Sorry, I'm not going to look at your github link. Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. I realize that formatting in comments is difficult. That's because they're not intended to provide updates or clarifications. Those should be made in the question itself using [edit]. I stated this in my comment. Please read and understand what people are trying to tell you and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information missing here, but I suspect your problem boils down to the following three facts.

1. A standard array must necessarily always contain elements of the same *type*. It cannot, e.g. contain a 'string' in one index, and a 'number' in another; that's what cell arrays are for.
2. Attempting to convert a cell array which contains such mixed elements into a standard array via cell2mat should, depending on your warning / error levels, either fail, or convert all elements to their least common denominator. E.g. if you have both 'date strings' (like '2011-01-02') and 'numbers', it will probably interpet the 'numbers' as ascii character codes first.
3. Strings in octave are simply arrays of characters. If you try to vertically concatenate two strings which are of unequal length, you will get an error about mismatched dimensions, since the resulting array in a concatenation always needs to be properly rectangular.

E.g. if all strings are same size (note numeric conversion)

```
> c = { '2011-01-01', 98.1; '2011-01-20', 97 };
> C = cell2mat(c)
warning: implicit conversion from numeric to char
  C =
    2011-01-01b
    2011-01-20a
```

If they're not (note the unpadded date):

```
> c = { '2011-01-01'; '2011-01-2' };
> C = cell2mat(c)
error: cat: dimension mismatch
error: called from
    cell2mat at line 80 column 11
```

I don't know the exact nature of the cell array resulting from your `csv2cell` operation, but I would wager something similar to the above is going on.

In general, it is probably not the right approach to convert via cell2mat immediately. Instead, you could probably collect all columns to separate variables, and then treat them accordingly, either via `cell2mat` or via a `cellfun` approach.